# Hard Coding my UUID into Android app, unsuccessful

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-bluetooth

My code:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device){
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        try{
            tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord("myID",d364b420-8d71-11e3-baa8-0800200c9a66);

        } catch (IOException e){}
        mmSocket = tmp;

    }
}
```

I researched UUID's [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29) and it wants a name and the UUID, but i get an error saying either the Type BluetoothDevice is not applicable to the argument(withought the UUID in the argument, or it will say the UUID i provide cannot be resolved into a variable. Am I wrong in thinking i need a name and a uuid for the argument of the function createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord? Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you elaborate your question what do you want ? i have already worked on the bluetooth stuff.

Comment: [createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)) takes an [UUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html) as argument. Use it like this: `tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("d364b420-8d71-11e3-baa8-0800200c9a66"));`

Comment: Balu, I was wondering if the function createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord takes 2 arguments in, which would be the name and the actual UUID itself, but apparently it takes one, as Jasper has answered. Still looking into it

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid syntax:

```
tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord("myID",d364b420-8d71-11e3-baa8-0800200c9a66);
```

First of all, the method takes only one argument, and that's an `UUID`, according to the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html).

Ofcourse you cannot just put the UUID there as a literal like you do. It has to be an `UUID` object. Try something like this:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("d364b420-8d71-11e3-baa8-0800200c9a66");
tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
```